# visual studio 2010 - webform design (buttons)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to place a row of buttons or link buttons next to each other on a webform without a white space showing between them when viewed in the browser?

thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters once you get to the "when viewed in the browser" stage in the process, you're well outside of Visual Studio and into straight HTML/CSS.  In HTML/CSS, [this can be done](http://jsfiddle.net/4JTpd/):

```
<input type="button" value="test" /><input type="button" value="test" /><input type="button" value="test" /><input type="button" value="test" /><input type="button" value="test" />
```

and

```
input { margin: -1px; }
```

Using CSS is generally the best way to do this, rather than trying to come up with some custom thing within Visual Studio.  It's more native to the target platform, the web browser.  The CSS in my example would cover all `input` elements on the page, of course, so you probably don't want that.  But if you can uniquely identify your rendered buttons (perhaps `input` elements within a `div` of a known `id`?) then you can apply that style only to them.